# OnLButtonUp not firing after mouse click for CStatic control

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC application where I am trying to let the user draw a rectangle via mouse drag over a picture control.  I created my own PictureCtrl class subclassed by CStatic.  However, the OnLButtonUp() is not firing when I do any mouse clicks.

```
void PictureCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    SetCapture();

    anchor = point;
    CRect rect(point,point);

    CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    pDC->DrawDragRect(&rect, CSize(1,1), NULL, CSize(1,1), NULL, NULL);
    m_lastRect = rect;
    ReleaseDC(pDC);

    CStatic::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);

}

void PictureCtrl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    if(GetCapture() == this) 
    {
        CRect rect(anchor, point);
        rect.NormalizeRect();

        CDC *pDC = GetDC();
        pDC->DrawDragRect(&rect, CSize(1,1), &m_lastRect, CSize(1,1), NULL, NULL);
        m_lastRect = rect;
        ReleaseDC(pDC);

        ReleaseCapture();
    }

    CStatic::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

void PictureCtrl::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    if(GetCapture() == this) 
    {
        CDC *pDC = GetDC();
        CRect rect(0,0,0,0);
        pDC->DrawDragRect(rect, CSize(1,1), &m_lastRect, CSize(1,1), NULL, NULL);
        ReleaseDC(pDC);

        ReleaseCapture();
    }

    CStatic::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}
```

If anyone could give me any insight to why the OnLButtonUp is not firing that would be appreciated.  Is it because the OnMouseMove is eating up all the calls when i drag my mouse?

Also, can anyone give me a suggestion on how to modify my code so that if a rectangle has already been drawn, if the user draws a new one the old rectangle will be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `ReleaseCapture()` in `OnMouseMove` or you'll miss `OnLButtonUp` if the mouse is outside of the window.  Regarding your rectangle, use regular drawing primitives not dragging ones once the rectangle is complete.

Comment: Also make sure you have `ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()` in your `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`-`END_MESSAGE_MAP` block.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks!  I thought I had I had mapped it but guess not.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the old rectangle and then draw a new one use a special pen that doesn't have a color of its own but inverts the existing image pixels. Then drawing over the old rect will erase it. See the example in WM_MOUSEMOVE here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145184(v=vs.85).aspx